# Can't seem to work out Applescript UI elements

Tags: applescript

Event after using **UI elements** and **entire contents**, I can't seem to write the correct Applescript to select the button in the below hierarchy:

[image]

It's like the button and the popover aren't accessible? Here's the ui element I'm trying to click on:

[image]

Here's the output from UI Browser:
[image]

I can at least bring up the popover with the below:

```
launch application "System Events"
delay 0.4

ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Noizio"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end ignoring
delay 0.1
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
Rob

Comment: What does your script return with only this line of code any nothing else: `tell application "System Events" to tell process "Noizio" to click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2`. You'll want the `"Replies"` pane open at the bottom of _Script Editor_. It will run for about 5 seconds before returning a result.  If the result is `missing value`, then I imagine your popover did not appear and you're out of luck.  If it returns anything else apart from an error, you _should_ see the popover appear as well.  If not, you're also out of luck.

Comment: This is one of the few occasions where Automator's `Watch Me Do` action is actually useful.  Just fire up Automator, click the `Record` button, do your stuff, and stop recording.  The events will appear in the action table view and can be pasted into the Script Editor, where you can see the UI elements and various time delays (at least at the time the workflow was run).

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. CJK, yeah it returned missing value. red_menace, I've tried that but it actually doesn't work. I think this is because the popover seems to not have any parent element.